# Python MySQL execute query loop with cursor close

Tags: python, mysql-python

This is the reproduced sample:

```
import mysql.connector

conn =  mysql.connector.connect(
  user='root', password='12347',
  host='localhost')

def getCursor():
  return conn.cursor()

def execQuery(cursor=getCursor()):
  cursor.execute("SELECT 2")
  cursor.fetchall()
  cursor.close()

for i in range(4):
  cursor = execQuery()
```

This code works without `cursor.close()`. But what I find weird is that this sample works even with cursor.close() with a simple change:

```
def execQuery():
  cursor=getCursor()
  cursor.execute("SELECT 2")
  cursor.fetchall()
  cursor.close()
```

By moving the default parameter to the body of the function.

I don't know if it's the best practice to close the cursor, so I can skip closing cursor while keeping the first form. If it's not the best practice to have a default parameter that uses return value of a function, I can go with the second form. **But I want to why they act differently**

It's like I'm having the same error as the following:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT 2")
cursor.fetchall()
cursor.close()
cursor.execute("SELECT 2")
```

It's like every call of execQuery is using the same cursor, so it gets blocked right at the second call.

Answer (score 0):

When you need to connect to Database you need something like cursor. You need a cursor object to fetch results.

In the sample program when you run loop in range (4) it calls `execQuery()` . Looking into definition you can find `def execQuery(cursor=getCursor()):` the function takes input as cursor and by default it used `getCursor()` function which creates cursor everything when the loop is executed.

While in your program you are closing the cursor but not creating it again hence when second execute query comes there is no cursor present and the program throws an error.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think 'function which creates cursor everything when ...' should be 'cursor *every time*', No?

Comment: Anyways, from what I understand from your answer, every time `execQuery` is called in the loop, it creates cursor. Then you say that I close the cursor and not creating it again. Are you saying that when the `execQuery` is executed the second time, cursor is not created, because it was closed? Can you please tell me why it's not created again please?